# How to find the indexs of a sequence of values in a list?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, signal-processing

I'm trying to find sequences of 200 labels and return their indexes. Here is my first attempt but I'm sure there must be a better way(faster)...

Sequences must be multiples of 200 and next sequence is less than 200 then reject it.

[This image shows what my code does at the moment with labels at the top and indexes on the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYSnz.png)

For a signal processing problem. New to python.

```
indexs = []
zeros = [0]*200
ones = [1]*200
twos = [2]*200
threes = [3]*200
fours = [4]*200
fives = [5]*200
i=0
while i < range(len(labels)):

    if i+200 > len(labels):
        break

    if labels[i:i+len(zeros)] == zeros:
        indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
        i+=200
        continue
    if labels[i:i+len(ones)] == ones:
        indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
        i+=200
        continue
    if labels[i:i+len(twos)] == twos:
        indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
        i+=200
        continue
    if labels[i:i+len(threes)] == threes:
        indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
        i+=200
        continue
    if labels[i:i+len(fours)] == fours:
        indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
        i+=200
        continue
    if labels[i:i+len(fives)] == fives:
        indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
        i+=200
        continue
    i+=1
```

EDIT:

Thanks for all the feedback people it is much appreciated. I think I should mention that I'm working with arrays that are 1M+ in size and are dense in that they are mostly blocks of 200. Therefore, I thought a while loop would allow me to skip the majority of loops. Part of my plan is to reduce the dimensionality by taking averages of these 200 blocks but also create a number of features for a classifier. I'm following a similar method in the paper http://www.cis.fordham.edu/wisdm/includes/files/sensorKDD-2010.pdf.

Here's similar (but smaller) generated data

```
labels = [0]*1250+[1]*15400+[0]*12245+[5]*1204*[4]*20045
```

Edit2: heres some neater code taking on some of your advice

```
def tensequencer(df):
    labels = df.activity.as_matrix().tolist()
    #find and store all indexs
    indexs = []
    zeros = [0]*200
    ones = [1]*200
    twos = [2]*200
    threes = [3]*200
    fours = [4]*200
    fives = [5]*200
    numbers = [zeros, ones, twos, threes, fours, fives]
    i=0
    while i < range(len(labels)):

        if i+200 > len(labels):
            break

        if labels[i:i+200] in numbers  :
            indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(zeros))))
            i+=200
            continue

        i+=1


    #index dataframe


    df = df.iloc[indexs,:]
    df.index=range(df.shape[0])
    return df
```

Comment: Well, each `if` has exactly the same content, so there might be something wrong there.

Comment: You haven't initialized **labels** in this code, nor does it produce any output.  Not something we can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Scan through the labels, keeping track of how long the sequence of identical numbers is that ends with the current value.  Whenever that sequence meets your criteria (i.e. is long enough), add it to indexes.

One wrinkle: say there is a run of 400 3's.  It isn't clear from your description if this should be counted as 2 sequences of 200 or 1 of 400 or both.  If just the longest, then don't decide about adding to indices until a run ends.

Answer (score 0):

You know ahead of time how many iterations you need: use a **for** loop:

```
for i in range(len(labels) - 200):
```

That eliminates your **break** statement.

Next, you have six nearly identical sets of check sequences.  Drop all six into a single list (of lists), and you can run a loop range(6) for your label checks.

Even better, are you familiar with **map** and **reduce**?  You could do a nice one-line check, asking whether *each* element in labels[i+1:i+200] is equal to labels[0].  That would eliminate the six-fold check.

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

I won't discuss the algorithm, just will make adjustments to the code.
You can use sets to check if an list of 200 elements is made of a single repeated element.

```
for i in range(len(labels) - 200):
    interval = labels[i:i+200]
    reduced = set(interval)
    if len(reduced) == 1:
        repeated_number = reduced.pop()

    # You have founded the number repeated 200 times consecutively.
    # Now do whatever you wish with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will be faster in terms of execution, but that'll definitely be 
better to maintain :

```
indexs = []
for i in range(len(labels)):
    if i+200 > len(labels):
        break
    for j in range(0,6):
        cset = [j] * 200
        if labels[i:i+len(cset)] == cset:
            indexs.extend((range(i,i+len(cset))))
            i += 200
            break
```